# Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, polly

This is my code:

```cs
var policy = Policy
              .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
              .RetryAsync(1);

HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;
await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
 httpResponse = await _graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(batchRequest);
});
```

This worked fine. I modified the code to:

```cs
var policy = Policy
              .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
              .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
              .RetryAsync(1);
```

then it returns this error:

> Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type `Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>`

Comment: Please post your entire function where you're configuring your `policy` - and the **entire** compiler error message. I think the compile error is on a different line. Have you done a rebuild?

Comment: @user989988 You just need to add the following statement at the end of your `ExecuteAsync`'s delegate: `return httpResponse;`.

Answer (score 3):

In short, for Polly to be able to *inspect* a return value, you need to return something `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

**Example**

```
httpResponse = await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () 
    => await _graphClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage()));
     // ^ this is now returning a HttpResponseMessage
```

**The longer story**

The difference in the `ExecuteAsync` signatures are as follows

```
// this just expects a task, which can be supplied with an async lamda
public Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action)
```

Compared to when using `OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>`

```
// this expects a task<T> and needs a return value
public Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> action)
```

Or said another way

In your original code, you were just setting the `HttpResponse` message as a side effect of the *lambda*, which makes `ExecuteAsync` resolve to the overload signature `Func<Task> action`

```
await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    httpResponse = await _graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(batchRequest);
});
```

However, when you use `OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>` there is no such overload, which makes sense. Polly can't inspect a result if you don't supply one to it.